# Pearl necklace combinations

Tags: combinatorics

A string contains 36 different pearls: 12 blue, 12 green and 12 red. When the strings ends are unconnected the number of possible combinations to arrange the pearls is $36 \choose 12 $ $\times $ $24 \choose 12 $. Is this correct?

Now the real problem is when the strings ends are connected and a regular pearl necklace is formed. How many different combination does this thing have? It obviously is less than the unconnected case due to the symmetry necklace has. My friend argues that it's just 
$$\frac{\binom{36}{12}\times \binom{24}{12}}{36} $$
but I beg to differ. I don't get how the symmetry really affects to this but I don't think you can just divide by 36 the original case. Would you care to explain how to do this?

Comment: Dividing by $36$ will not give you the correct answer. Necklace problems are generally limited to rotational symmetry.

Comment: The following link at [MSE meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions#13335) may be helpful here and includes cookbook type explanations (scroll down to necklaces and bracelets).

Answer (score 2):

This is a table of the number of necklaces fixed by each rotation. Anything not present is $0$.
$$\begin{matrix}
e & \binom{36}{12}\binom{24}{12}\\
3 & 6\\
6 & \binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\\
9 & \binom{9}{3}\binom{6}{3}\\
12& \binom{12}{4}\binom{8}{4}\\
15& 6\\
18& \binom{18}{6}\binom{12}{6}\\
21& 6\\
24& \binom{12}{4}\binom{8}{4}\\
27& \binom{9}{3}\binom{6}{3}\\
30& \binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\\
33& 6
\end{matrix}$$

Toss these into (not) Burnside's Lemma (each $a_i$ from the table):

$$\frac{1}{36}\sum a_i = \frac{1}{36}(3384731762521200 + 2(6 + 90 + 1680 + 34650 + 6) + 17153136)$$
$$=94,020,327,215,200$$

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to do this using the Polya Enumeration Theorem.
The [cycle index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_index#Cyclic_group_Cn)
$Z(C_{36})$ of the cyclic group of order $36$ is
$$1/36\,{a_{{1}}}^{36}+1/36\,{a_{{2}}}^{18}
\\ +1/18\,{a_{{3}}}^{12}+1/18\,{a_{{4}          
}}^{9}+1/18\,{a_{{6}}}^{6}+1/6\,{a_{{9}}}^{4}
\\+1/9\,{a_{{12}}}^{3}+1/6\,{a_{{18}}}^{2}+1/3\,a_{{36}}.$$

Now doing the cycle index substitution 
$$a_k = R^k + G^k +B^k$$
we see that only the divisors of $12$ contribute.

These contributions are
$$\frac{1}{36} {36\choose 12,12,12}
+ \frac{1}{36} {18\choose 6,6,6}
+ \frac{1}{18} {12\choose 4,4,4}
\\ + \frac{1}{18} {9\choose 3,3,3}
+ \frac{1}{18} {6\choose 2,2,2}
+ \frac{1}{9} {3\choose 1,1,1}.$$

This yields
$$94020326736700 + 476476 + 1925 +
280/3 + 5 + 2/3 = 94020327215200.$$

The substituted cycle index looks like this:
$$1/36\, \left( R+G+B \right) ^{36}+1/36\, \left( {B}^{2}+{G}^{2}+{R}^{
2} \right) ^{18}+1/18\, \left( {B}^{3}+{G}^{3}+{R}^{3} \right) ^{12}
\\ +1/18\, \left( {B}^{4}+{G}^{4}+{R}^{4} \right) ^{9}+1/18\, \left( {B}^
{6}+{G}^{6}+{R}^{6} \right) ^{6}+1/6\, \left( {B}^{9}+{G}^{9}+{R}^{9}
 \right) ^{4}\\+1/9\, \left( {B}^{12}+{G}^{12}+{R}^{12} \right) ^{3}+1/
6\, \left( {B}^{18}+{G}^{18}+{R}^{18} \right) ^{2}+1/3\,{B}^{36}+1/3
\,{G}^{36}+1/3\,{R}^{36}.$$

The cycle index formula is
$$Z(C_n) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{d|n} \varphi(d) a_d^{n/d}.$$

Observe that ${36\choose 12,12,12}$ is a sixteen digit number.